# Write to a specific value in dataframe without overwriting the csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like such:

```
 master_contact_id  Agent_Disposition        QA_Disposition Comments
0           37284773    Not Serviceable       Not Serviceable      NaN
1           37284829  Existing Customer      Customer Service      NaN
2           37284880      Closed - Sale         Closed - Sale      NaN
3           37284887  Existing Customer  Hang up/Disconnected      NaN
4           37284943      Closed - Sale         Closed - Sale      NaN
```

I'm going through each contact id, finding the specific index, and writing a comment to replace "NaN" with:

```
df.at[1, 'Comments'] = "Test Comment"
```

However, when I write to csv, with

```
export = df.to_csv('set1_output.csv')
```

the exported csv keeps overwriting. I want to be able to append comments continually.

Comment: Please edit your question to be a bit clearer. Forget the idea of “overwriting the csv”, what matters is which DataFrame you’re modifying, and which one is written to a csv file. If you want to make a copy of a DataFrame, you can just do `df_copy = df.copy()` Another thing, writing `export = df.to_csv("set1_output.csv”)` is useless in the code you shared above. I have a few ideas of what might help, but I can’t do much without more information from you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to append the new data to the csv.

Make a copy of the dataframe, do your operations, append the new array to the old array, and save the whole copy.

```
dfcopy = df.copy()
dfcopy.at[1,"Comments"] = "Test Comment"
df.append(dfcopy)
export = df.to_csv('set1_output.csv')
```